# How to replace space with span PHP?

Tags: php

I am using this to split my title by space and make the first word a span for additional color styling,

```
$title = 'My new title';
$title = explode(' ', $title);
$title[0] = '<span>'.$title[0].'</span>';
$title= join(' ', $title);
```

As you can see I catch only first one in this case. 
What would be the fastest/best/correct way to wrap all title words in span ?

Comment: Don't worry about "fastest".  Worry about "correct".

Comment: ok , what would be the correct away ?

Comment: This seems like an easy answer.. for line 3, use `foreach ($title as $key => $t) { $title[$key] = '<span>'.$t.'</span>'; }`

Comment: full code [there](http://3v4l.org/IAfNf) it is like jsfiddle

Comment: @gbestard ever seen people asking question to simplify the codes? I dont think I left room for smart comments. If you dont like people asking questions than you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way. Simple and Easy.

```
str_replace(" ", "</span><span>", $title);
$title = "<span>$title</span>";
```

Comment: this is something I was aiming for , without the loops, testing

Comment: perfect , was just missing the space after </span><span>

Comment: Just make `"</span><span>"` as `"</span> <span>"`. Any programmer would do that... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` loop to do that:

```
$title = 'My new title';
$title = explode(' ', $title);
foreach ($title as $k => $v){
    $title[$k] = '<span>'.$v.'</span>';
}
$title= join(' ', $title);

echo $title;
```

Comment: thnx lars , this one is also clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = 'My new title';
$title = explode(' ', $title);
foreach($title  as $v)
{
  echo $ti = '<span>'.$v.'</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk)

```
$title = 'My new title';
$title = explode(' ', $title);
$title = array_walk($title, function(&$word) { return '<span>'.$word.'</span>'; })
$title= implode(' ', $title);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function span($n){
    return('<span>'.$n.'</span>');
}

$title = 'My new title';
$title = explode(' ', $title);
$title = join(' ', array_map("span", $title));
print_r($title);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers, but here's an alternative solution using regular expressions:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\S+/', '<span>\0</span>', $title);
```

Comment: Don't you think a regular expression is overkill?

Comment: @MueR Perhaps, just offering it as an alternative.

Comment: to heavy , preg is to much for something like this

Answer (score 0):

Preg replace

```
$title = "My new title";
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/i', '<span>$1</span>', $title);
```